# error while saving large matrix using scipy.io.savemat

Tags: python, matlab, scipy

i want to save a large matrix of 20Gb in matlab(`.mat`) format using `scipy.io.savemat` function.While i am saving at that time it gives me error as follow:

error is:

`scipy.io.savemat` matrix too large to save with Matlab `5` format

My code is

```
 scipy.io.savemat('output.mat',mdict={'data':data})
```

I hope experts may give some suggestion to overcome the above problem.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Given how old the `mat` format is I'm not surprise that there's a size limit like this.  Saving it as chunks might be possible.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I agree with @hpaulj. I think there is no other way than saving it in smaller chunks than 20GB... Is that at all possible for you? Maybe you can orient your solution on the layout of your data-structure, i.e. if it's a 3-dimensional matrix saving slices along the 3rd axis.